# Is there a way to curve the tabbar indicator down in the corners?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I've put a border radius on the container in a scaffold. What I want now is for the TabBar indicator to curve down along with the container instead of a straight line which results in the indicator to float above the background. The image will show what I mean.

I've tried playing around with the indicator property of the TabBar, but without any success.

[Picture of the app as example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgXNu.png)

[Picture of result that I'm looking for (Photoshop)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXq9T.png)

wrapper.dart

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => StoreConnector<AppState, Store<AppState>>(
  converter: (Store<AppState> store) => store,
  builder: (BuildContext context, Store<AppState> store) => Container(
      decoration: widget.decoration,
      child: Scaffold(
        drawer: widget.drawer ? _menuDrawer(context, store) : null,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(widget.tabBar != null ? 110.0 : 60.0),
            child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: AppBar(
                  actions: widget.actions,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.white),
                  title: widget.teamIsPremium != null
                      ? Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(widget.teamIsPremium ? MdiIcons.star : MdiIcons.starOff),
                            Container(
                              width: 5,
                            ),
                            Text(widget.title),
                          ],
                        )
                      : Text(widget.title),
                  centerTitle: true,
                  elevation: 0,
                  bottom: widget.tabBar,
                ))),
        bottomNavigationBar: widget.selectedMenuItem == WrapperMenuItem.NONE
            ? null
            : Theme(
                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme),
                child: BottomNavigationBar(
                    selectedItemColor: Color(0xff2e2e2e),
                    unselectedItemColor: Color(0xff757575),
                    currentIndex: _getIdFromEnum(widget.selectedMenuItem),
                    onTap: (i) => {
                          if (i != _getIdFromEnum(widget.selectedMenuItem))
                            {widget.selectedMenuItem = _getWrapperMenuItemFromId(i), _moveToPage(context, i)}
                        },
                    showSelectedLabels: true,
                    items: [
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(MdiIcons.home), title: Text('Start')),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(MdiIcons.trafficCone), title: Text('Trainingen')),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(MdiIcons.trophy), title: Text('Wedstrijden')),
                      BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(MdiIcons.accountGroup), title: Text('Spelers'))
                    ]),
              ),
        body: Container(
          margin: widget.small
              ? EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, top: 5)
              : widget.tabBar != null ? EdgeInsets.only(top: 0) : EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: widget.transparent ? Colors.transparent : Color.fromRGBO(240, 240, 240, 1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15))),
          constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
          alignment: Alignment(-1, -1),
          child: ClipRRect(
            child: widget.child,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(15), topRight: Radius.circular(15)),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: widget.floatingActionButton,
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
      )));
```

match.dart

```
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Wrapper(
          title: 'Wedstrijden',
          drawer: true,
          selectedMenuItem: WrapperMenuItem.MATCH,
          tabBar: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'Overzicht'),
              Tab(text: 'Statistieken'),
            ],
          ),
          child: TabBarView(
            children: [
              MatchOverviewTab(),
              MatchStatsTab(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Probably dumb thing to offer, but maybe it helps) You know which of the screens will be shown MatchOverviewTab() or MatchStatsTab(), so you can actually try to draw that curved orange line on them [one from the left, another from the right]

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try, remember everything is a widget in the flutter, so first, create **Stack** inside your scaffold inside that place your **TabBar()** and **Container()** using Positioned or any other such that they overlap to the desired extent then you should add your [Custom Indicator](https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-custom-tab-indicator-for-tabbar-d72bbc6c9d0c) (This would a Container with rounded edges in your case)to the **TabBar()**.

---

Here is an image for more clarity.
[image]

Of course, there are several possible ways to do it but this is what I can think of and you will see the same indicator animation too.
curious to know if it worked.